# Python BeautifulSoup text between the tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from the following HTML code

```
    <html>
        <body>
            Other Contents here that I dont care about
            <ul class="normalDays">
                <li>
                    <span>
                        Monday
                    </span>
                    8:00 to 18:00
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                        Friday
                    </span>
                    8:00 to 18:00
                </li>
                <!-- Other days as well -->
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to extract data from this code snippet. I want to extract the day and the hours corresponding to it. So far I have tried this in Python

```
    trade=i.find("ul",{"class":"normalDays"})
    day=trade.find_all("span")
    for dy in day:
        if dy.string=='Monday':
            print(dy.string+":"+str(dy.parent.text.replace("Monday","")))
```

But I want to extract the data without the need of putting if conditions for 7 days. How can I extract the days and the times directly from the HTML code and assign the time to the day and then put it in a dictionary where keys are days Monday to Sunday and values are the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  


soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
normals_days = soup.find('ul', class_='normalDays').findAll('li')

days = {}
for day in normals_days:
    day = day.text.split()
    days[day[0]] = ' '.join(day[1:])
```